# Why are files sent through Gmail renamed?

Tags: gmail

Why is it if I download an image sent to me through Gmail the filename of the image was changed into downloadfile? Is there a way that the filename won't be changed after downloading it from Gmail?

Samsung Galaxy 5, if it matters.

Comment: I'm not sure if this will solve your problem, so I'll leave a comment: does using app such as "Save my Attach" help your problem?

Comment: I tried to replicate the issue but on my EVO images downloaded in the Gmail App don't get the name changed.  This happens to every image you try to download?

Comment: I've only noticed this with failed/partial downloads (from anywhere) - when I've had particular problems with something I've ended up with 'downloadfile', 'downloadfile-1', 'downloadfile-2', etc. Otherwise, I'm sure my downloaded files keep the original filenames.

Comment: I think FoleyIsGood is on to something there.  Verify that your download is completing and its the whole file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newest version of the Gmail app supports file downloads, rather than previews.  If you're using the website I would think that Foley is correct.